# How to query using objectify in Google App Engine app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have one entity called MemberInfo and another entity called PaymentInfo.

```
@Parent
@Index
private Key<MemberInfo> memberInfo;
private double aCharges;
private double bCharges;
private double cCharges;
```

//And my query is as below

```
 Query<PaymentInfo> query = OfyService.ofy().load().type(PaymentInfo.class);
        Key<PaymentInfo> memberInfoKey = Key.create(PaymentInfo.class,membershipId);
        query = query.filter("=", memberInfoKey);
        return query.list();
```

---

Above is code that I have written but I am getting null result. I want result from PaymentInfo entity whose memberId is in Member entity

I want to query on PaymentInfo and get result of different payments paid by particular Member using memberId in MemberInfo in PaymentInfo. I have different fields like charges and one more field as `@Parent Key<MemberInfo>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to add the name of the field that you are filtering on in your filter call, so `query.filter("=", memberInfoKey)` would become `query.filter("memberInfo", memberInfoKey)`

This is how I've managed to get it working before, and here are the [docs](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries) with some more examples